# How time and speed of light are related?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time, inertial-frames

I want to know how speed and light and time are related? How will motion with highspeed effect time?

I am not a physics student. I want an answer which is free of mathematical relations. I want an insight rather than a mathematical relation.
please answer.

Comment: I already said I am not a physics student, so your downvoting doesnt make any sense.

Comment: Hi Rayees. This site is for, and I quote from the tour, *active researchers, academics and students of physics and astronomy*. That doesn't mean we don't accept questions from non-physicists but we expect them to have put the same degree of effort into their question as we'd expect from a physicist. Your question basically just says *tell me about relativity* and shows no effort on your part to research the subject. That will be why you're getting downvotes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 3):

> I want an answer which is free of mathematical relations.I want an
>   insight rather than a mathematical relation.

[Very well](http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/Special_relativity_clocks_rods/).

[image]

Do you see?

Comment: "You might still be tempted to say that the other clock would not keep pace with the light clock. Instead,
you might say, it would keep
running at just the same speed as it did when at rest. But then you would have devised a device that detects absolute motion"

Please explain this a bit I do not understand here.
What is absolute motion.